# Slow ResNet50 training time using AWS Sagemaker GPU instance

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to train a ResNet50 model using keras with tensorflow backend. I'm using a sagemaker GPU instance **ml.p3.2xlarge** but my training time is extremely long. I am using conda_tensorflow_p36 kernel and I have verified that I have tensorflow-gpu installed.

When inspecting the output of nvidia-smi I see the process is on the GPU, but the utilization is never above **0%**.

[image]

Tensorflow also recognizes the GPU.
[image]

Screenshot of training time.
[image]

Is sagemaker in fact using the GPU even though the usage is **0%?**
Could the long epoch training time be caused by another issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've completed 8 steps and it just takes very long. What's your step time?
It might be due to data loading. Where ia data stored? Try to take data loading out of the picture by caching and feeding a single image to the DNN repeatedly and see if that helps.

Comment: See this blog post for optimized data loading in SageMaker: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/choose-the-best-data-source-for-your-amazon-sagemaker-training-job/